# Why is Python insisting on using ascii?

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When parsing an HTML file with Requests and Beautiful Soup, the following line is throwing an exception on some web pages:

```
if 'var' in str(tag.string):
```

Here is the context:

```
response = requests.get(url)  
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text.encode('utf-8'))

for tag in soup.findAll('script'):
    if 'var' in str(tag.string):    # This is the line throwing the exception
        print(tag.string)
```

Here is the exception:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)

I have tried both with and without using the `encode('utf-8')` function in the `BeautifulSoup` line, it makes no difference. I do note that for the pages throwing the exception there is a character `Ã` in a comment in the javascript, even though the encoding reported by response.encoding is `ISO-8859-1`. I do realise that I can remove the offending characters with unicodedata.normalize however I would prefer to convert the `tag` variable to `utf-8` and keep the characters. None of the following methods help to change the variable to `utf-8`:

```
tag.encode('utf-8')
tag.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
tag.decode(response.encoding).encode('utf-8')
```

What must I do to this string in order to transform it into usable `utf-8`?

Comment: You try those methods but kept doing: `if 'var' in str(tag.string):`??

Comment: @PauloBu: No, I use of course the output of the conversion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so basically you're getting an HTTP response encoded in `Latin-1`. The character giving you problem es indeed `Ã` because looking [here](http://www.lingua-systems.com/knowledge/unicode-mappings/iso-8859-1-to-unicode.html) you may see that `0xC3` is exactly that character in Latin-1.

I think you blinded test every combination you imagined about decoding/encoding the request. First of all, if you do this: `if 'var' in str(tag.string):` whenever `string` var contains non-ASCII bytes, python will complaint.

Looking at the code you've shared with us, the right approach IMHO would be:

```
response = requests.get(url)
# decode the latin-1 bytes to unicode  
#soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text.decode('latin-1'))
#try this line instead
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, from_encoding=response.encoding)

for tag in soup.findAll('script'):
    # since now soup was made with unicode strings I supposed you can treat
    # its elements as so
    if u'var' in tag.string:    # This is the line throwing the exception
        # now if you want output in utf-8
        print(tag.string.encode('utf-8'))
```

**EDIT:** It will be useful for you to take a look at [the encoding section from the BeautifiulSoup 4 doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings)

Basically, the logic is:

1. You get some bytes encoded in encoding `X`
2. You decode `X` by doing `bytes.decode('X') and this returns a unicode byte sequence`
3. You work with unicode
4. You encode the unicode to some encoding `Y` for the output `ubytes.encode('Y')`

Hope this bring some light to the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of `response.text.decode('latin-1')` I am trying `response.text.decode(response.encoding)` because this application needs to work with other sites as well. That very line is now throwing the error message (albeit with a different position, of course). Is there no generic way to work with any encoding?

Comment: What's the error now? This is the way to work with whatever encoding. You get the response encoding, decode it, work with unicode and encode int utf-8. What error is throwing now and how does `response.encoding` looks like?

Comment: Same error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5837-5838: ordinal not in range(128)`, now on this line: `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text.decode(response.encoding))` (all copied from the CLI error message). The page that I'm parsing in this example is http://www.poemhunter.com/poems/hate/ (not my site, just an example that I stumbled across).

Comment: I edited the code in my answer when instantiation of BeautifulSoup object. Also gave you a link to the docs which will be useful. I'll take a look at that page. Notify me if it worked.

Comment: Thank you, sending the encoding as you mention with `from_encoding=` does seem to help! I'm testing now. Thank you for the link to the relevant part of the documentation.

Comment: You're most welcome. I tested the page and was able to parse it correctly with `bs4`, although I did it with normal `urllib2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use Unicode Dammit lib(it is part of BS4) to parse pages. Detailed description here: http://scriptcult.com/subcategory_176/article_852-use-beautifulsoup-unicodedammit-with-lxml-html.html